# How to enable hot reload in flutter run for web application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

For mobile emulation hot reload we use `flutter run --watch`.
How to enable hot reload when running flutter for web application with `flutter run -d chrome` ?. I have tried watch command argument like `flutter run --watch -d chrome` and `flutter run -d chrome --watch` but both gave me warning message.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio (which is something i recommend), as soon as you save dart file, hot reload triggers, but be careful sometimes you need to manually click on Play button (without stopping the current run)